# There are no rules: D15 R0 D22

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Rule 1: There are no rules

Rule 2: When in doubt, see rule 1

The puzzle is to find the next two items in the following sequence:

`D15 R0 D22 R13 R-13 D11 ...`

### Hints

1. This puzzle is related to something "in the real world". If you are looking for a purely mathematical way to solve this you are on the wrong path.
2. This puzzle has to do with American Politics.

Comment: I have an idea about this - I don't think it's *impossible*, but it is potentially *extremely tedious*

Comment: This is not a riddle or a logic puzzle; please look at tag descriptions before using them.

Comment: Is the `-` in `R-13` put there intentionally?

Comment: @f'' - I noticed the same, but assumed it was reverse order, from current. So: Obama (D), Bush (R), Clinton (D), Bush (R), Reagan (R), Carter (D). Possibly making the next two Ford (R) & Nixon (R)...

Comment: @Alconja I get the feeling the D and R designations can't be *winners* since one of the numbers is negative, but they also don't seem like they're paired since they swap positions after the second "pair" (sorry about the late response to your comment, I just remembered this puzzle this morning)

Comment: @question_asker - I don't know enough US politics to take it further (nor the patience to research), but was thinking the numbers could be some sort of statistic from while that person was in office (eg. % national debt increase, change in number of bills approved,  etc), which would allow for negatives.

Comment: @Alconja That's a good point! Part of the reason I said I felt like it would be "tedious" above - I don't really want to crawl through stats until I locate the slice of time where those party designations and numbers matched.

Answer (score 6):

D donates Double, R is Reverse. solve the puzzle as a mirror in the middle.

Take Reverse -13 to 13.
Double 11 to 22.
so x= R0, y=D7.5

at least this one makes sense to me :)

Comment: How do you know Y isn't D30?

Comment: because the right hand side numbers are reflected according to the symbol on their left. It could be the other side, but the reflection works for all numbers and symbols given at least. This may not be the answer but the logic makes sense at least.